# Where does AWS OpenSearch domain endpoint points

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am new to OpenSearch or AWS in general. I was trying to debug a recent issue with OpenSearch service when I came across these docs

As per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/vpc.html) documentation:

> OpenSearch Service assigns each ENI a private IP address from the IPv4 address range of your subnet. The service also assigns a public DNS hostname (which is the domain endpoint) for the IP addresses. You must use a public DNS service to resolve the endpoint (which is a DNS hostname) to the appropriate IP addresses for the data nodes:

While [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-http-503-errors/) FAQ section says:

> A load balancer sits in front of each OpenSearch Service domain. The load balancer distributes incoming traffic to the data nodes.

Also, [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/set-access-control-for-amazon-elasticsearch-service/) blog says:

> When Amazon ES creates your domain, it launches instances into a service-controlled VPC. Those instances are fronted by Elastic Load Balancing (ELB), and the endpoint for the load balancer is published through Route 53. Requests to the domain pass through the ELB load balancer, which routes them to the domain’s EC2 instances.

When I tried dns lookup for the domain endpoint using [this](https://www.dnsqueries.com/en/dns_lookup.php) tool, I got the same number of A records as my data nodes in the OpenSearch service domain.

So does the OpenSearch domain name point to a load balancer or the data nodes?

Comment: I think the number is of az's rather than data nodes. If you have three az, then you should get 3 records. Needs to be checked.